# Is there a font that displays Chinese characters as their Latin equivalents?

Tags: fonts, language, unicode

Chinese, Japanese, and other languages with non-Latin characters (as used in English) now have wide support thanks to Unicode providing the necessary glyphs.  However for people who don't speak these languages, comparing two names or other text often involves a slow process of studying the glyphs and playing 'spot the difference'.

Is there a font that has these Unicode glyphs replaced with one that looks like a collection of Latin characters that represents the way the character is pronounced?

I'm not sure if this is even possible (I don't know whether some characters in these languages modify the meaning of those around it, but perhaps it's something that [font ligatures](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-3/signs-and-symbols/ligatures-1) could handle) however for someone who is unfamiliar with the characters it could save a lot of time if an approximation in their native language was available.

It would also be a lot faster than copying text into something like Google Translate, which is only really practical if what you're reading is a web page and not, say, a spreadsheet.

Is there a font like this available, or is there any other way to automatically replace non-Latin characters with their approximate Latin substitutes, without requiring special application support beyond UTF-8?

Comment: NOT a matter of fonts: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinyin

Comment: @MichaelBay: Are you saying this is something that ligatures cannot address, or that there are too many to be practical?

Comment: What I'm saying is you need to install Pinyin support. Example for Windows 10: https://www.pinyinjoe.com/windows-10/windows-10-pinyin-setup.htm

Comment: @MichaelBay: The link seems to be about input methods (entering Latin characters and having them display as Chinese glyphs) rather than displaying Chinese characters as Latin glyphs, unless I'm missing something?